# Action as Func in C#

Tags: c#, lambda, action, func

I have a parametric method that takes a `Func` as an argument

```
SomeType SomeMethod<T>( Func<T, T> f ) {...}
```

I would like to pass an `Action` without having to overload the method. But this takes to the problem, how do you represent and `Action` as a `Func`? I tried

```
Func<void, void>
```

but its not valid.

Comment: you **can't**.......

Comment: And never will be, Func does not allow void return types (because of that the existance of Action delegate). You can always wrap your Action into a lambda (o) => { ExecuteAction(); return true; }

Comment: Very good question, and also one that does not have a satisfactory answer in C#. You are running into this issue: http://james-iry.blogspot.com/2009/07/void-vs-unit.html

Comment: @Gusman yeah, It's basically what I am doing, but that makes me write an unnecessary return, which is what I am trying to solve.

Comment: If the return isn't necessary why does SomeMethod expect a Func? Surely it's using that return value.

Answer (score 12):

You can create an extension method to wrap an action and return a dummy value:

```
public static class ActionExtensions
{
    public static Func<T, T> ToFunc<T>(this Action<T> act)
    {
        return a => { act(a); return default(T) /*or a*/; };
    }
}

Action<?> act = ...;
SomeMethod(act.ToFunc());
```

It might be clearer if you create your own `Unit` type instead of using `object` and returning null.

Comment: Never used default, what does it do?

Comment: @CristianGarcia - It returns `null` for reference types and 'zero' for value types.

Comment: I get this error: `Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class`

Comment: @CristianGarcia - You have to define extension methods in static classes - see update.

Comment: @CristianGarcia Also, structs are value types that can't be set to 0. The default value of a struct is where all its value properties are set to 0 and its reference properties are set to null. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664475(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 3):

***[`.NET Fiddle`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RldU3d)***

What you are looking for is a "statement lambda" <sup>**[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)**</sup>.

A statement lambda is when you wrap your expression (right hand side) in curly braces `{}`. This allows for more than 1 statement to be used. For your specific example, you could do this:

```
void Main()
{
    Func<bool,bool> f = i => {SomeAction();return true;};
    Console.WriteLine(SomeMethod(f));
}

public T SomeMethod<T>( Func<T, T> f ) 
{
    return f(default(T));
}

public void SomeAction()
{
    Console.WriteLine("called");
}
```

output

```
called
True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't turn an `Action` into a `Func`. But you could wrap a call to the `Action` in a `Func`. For example, something like:

```
Action a = new Action<Foo>(f => { whatever });

Foo myFoo = ...;
Foo result = SomeMethod(new Func<Foo, Foo>(f => { a(myFoo); return myFoo; }));
```

(Don't have Visual Studio up at the moment, but I think you get the idea.)